# OSX: detect SPACEBAR down and up events

Tags: macos, event-handling, keystroke

I need to record several thousand short soundbites of my own speech (I'm training an acoustic model for a speech recognition engine)

So for each one,  a line of text presents itself on the screen and I have to speak it, and capture the audio into a .WAV

I found a sample project for recording the audio; now I am trying to figure out how to do keyboard input.

I would like to push the SPACEBAR down to start recording and release it to terminate the recording.

Can anyone get me started?  ( an example would be ideal! )

Sorry, this is probably really really basic -- I haven't done any coding in OS X before (though I have done a lot of iOS work so I am no stranger to Xcode and some of the frameworks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a basic Cocoa application, you can use the following methods of `NSResponder`, of which `NSView` is a subclass, to capture your desired key up/down events:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event;
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event;
```

Use `[event keyCode]` to get the key pressed.